# Angular 2 Callback after view update after a change in a model

Tags: angular

Is there a way to detect the rendering end after model change in angular2 .. to set up a  jquery plugin ( chosen ) after

Comment: are you trying to initialize a select element with chosen after the application has bootstrapped? and can you also let us know why specifically after rendering ?

Comment: I'm trying to make an Angular 2 Chosen Wrapper .. the options list is a one on the component properties. Chosen  in initialised in in onInit() lifecycle event .. but when the options properties is blnded on changed .. i must update Chosen by calling element.trigger('chosen:updated')   .. the problems is that the update class must be done after Angular has finished the rendering .. the onChange() lifecycle event is called after the binded options are changed but before the update of the view

Comment: and what goes wrong when calling chosen:updated from onChange(), it does not update the options? What happens if calling chosen:updated from a setTimeout()?

Comment: i've tried .. it didin't work

Answer (score 3):

new Callbacks have beeen added in alpha37 :

`AfterViewInit` and `AfterViewChecked`